# Make a file readable for multiple users the same time in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file-io, streamreader

I've a file in server named mail template.txt which is using as a template for mailing. So when mailing code execute this template content will takes and replaces with the fields and attached as the body of the mail. This is actually the plan
But the problem am afraid is if multiple users (100 or 1000 or more) takes the mailing application and obviously the file needs to open for reading simultaneously. So I believe that will make some errors like access denied. The file is already open or something like that..
So how can make a single file readable for multiple users the same time. According to the project am doing it may access by more than 10000 users simultaneously.
Am using **StreamReader** method for reading file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, make FileShare to ReadWrite:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(
       new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, 
           FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))){
}
```